# Rails Ajax Form: Cannot figure what am I doing wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

My form is not sending the necessary params params[:tag_ids] to controller. I cannot figure out what am I doing wrong?

Routes.rb

```
put 'posts_filter', to: 'articles#index', as: :posts_filter
```

Views/articles/index.html.haml

```
%ul{style: "list-style-type: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;"}
  = form_tag posts_filter_path, remote: true, method: :put do
    - @tags.each do |tag|
      - if tag.count_of_articles != 0
        %li.content
          = check_box_tag "tag_ids[]", tag.id, @selected_tag_ids.first.blank? ? true : @selected_tag_ids.include?(tag.id.to_s) ? true : false
          = "#{tag.name} (#{tag.count_of_articles})"
    = submit_tag "Filter", class: "btn"
```

controllers/articles_controller

```
def index
@tags = Tag.asc
logger.info params.inspect
if params[:tag_ids].present?
  logger.info params[:tag_ids].inspect
  @articles = Article.where(id: Tagging.pluck_taggable_ids(params[:tag_ids])).desc.page(params[:page]).per(24)
  @selected_tag_ids = params[:tag_ids]
else
  logger.info "nononoononononononono"
  @articles = Article.pub.desc.page(params[:page]).per(24)
  @selected_tag_ids = []
end
respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
end
```

end

Comment: Can you inspect the form in firebug or chrome developer tools and place the form data. please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your tab setting of sublime editor tab:2 and paste following code:

```
%ul{style: "list-style-type: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;"}
= form_tag posts_filter_path, remote: true, method: :put do
- @tags.each do |tag|
  - if tag.count_of_articles != 0
    %li.content
      = check_box_tag "tag_ids[]", tag.id, @selected_tag_ids.first.blank? ? true : @selected_tag_ids.include?(tag.id.to_s) ? true : false
      = "#{tag.name} (#{tag.count_of_articles})"
= submit_tag "Filter", class: "btn"
```

Problem was with ajax request....